# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PHP Session array

Tags: php, session

I am trying to maintain cart with session array wherein I can see that the session array has items but when I try to remove one items by passing item id with URL and then re-assigning all items to array apart from item to be removed, I get error : "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

```
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = $_GET["removep"];
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"]!=$product_code){
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"], 'price'=>$cart_itm["price"]);
        }
        $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: did you check $_SESSION["products"] have a value and not empty?

Comment: Yes Amir, As I have mentioned in question.

Comment: Sunil, this error when occurred your variable doesn't have value ? when you var_dump your $_SESSION["products"], whats is your code print out ?

Comment: Var_dump gives values: array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(25) "Bib Cock With Wall Flange" ["code"]=> string(8) "VT-43001" ["qty"]=> string(3) "100" ["price"]=> NULL } }

Answer (score 0):

Always check values

is it array? is it empty or not? you need to check it.

```
   if (!empty($_SESSION["products"]) && is_array($_SESSION["products"])) {
        //then do something
   }
```

key values not empty? etc

```
 !empty($cart_itm["name"]) ? $cart_itm["name"] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Condition on the first line should test if you have a non-empty array.

```
if(isset($_GET["removep"]) && is_array($_SESSION["products"]) && count($_SESSION['products'] > 0))
```

You can't make loops over non-array (or non-object) elements and over empty elements.

Comment: When I check all array count and is_array($_SESSION["products"]), I found count greater than 0 and  is_array($_SESSION["products"]) as true